# Why is there a space between the cells in my UITableView

Tags: uitableview, tvos

I have `UITableView` with 1 section and 10 rows with blue background. Why am I getting space between the cells? How do I remove it?

[image: tvOS Simulator]

Comment: What happens when they're focussed? How would you deal with focus if they were butted up?

Comment: @Wain I'v disabled focus by `canFocusRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @pechr this does not make affect the space. it only avoids the cell to be focused.

Comment: I think this extra space cannot be removed.CollectionView doesn't have this extra space.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behaviour on tvOS. This way there is space to scale up the cell which has focus without the scaled cell overlapping its neighbours.

Comment: You are saying that these spaces cannot be removed?

Answer (score -3):

To avoid spacing , you can set tableview background as your cell's contentView background.