# How to remove the default separator space in TVOS

Tags: uitableview, swift4, tvos

i have a tvOS application where in i have used a UITableView for this and there appears to be a space between cells.
Is there any way to remove those separator?

There is no `separatorStyle` in tvOS.
Found the similar question, 
[Why is there a space between the cells in my UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364236/why-is-there-a-space-between-the-cells-in-my-uitableview)
But this does not solve my problem.
Is it really not able to remove the space between rows in UITableView Rows in tvOS?
Thanks in advance
[image: Sample Application screen shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a space between the cells in my UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364236/why-is-there-a-space-between-the-cells-in-my-uitableview)

Comment: it't not a duplicate because it has not an acceptable answer.