# UITableView adds inter row spacing on tvOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, tvos

Table view adds additional spacing between rows and it seems like there is no way to remove it. At least I cannot find a related property for it. A question like this has already been asked here [Why is there a space between the cells in my UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364236/why-is-there-a-space-between-the-cells-in-my-uitableview), but the answer has not been given.

[image: ViewDebugger]**Is it possible to remove this spacing or padding?**